# How to check if the parameter is set or not on hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, configuration

How to check the value of a particular parameter(say io.sort.mb) on hadoop while I'm running a benchmark(say teragen)?

I know you can always go to configuration files and see that but I have many configuration files plus some parameters get overwritten(like number of map tasks).

I don't have GUI. Is there any command to see this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you set in the configuration files should be available in your job.xml. This should be available in your job tracker in the specific job entry.

Through a code these values will be available in the Configuration object.

Comment: Thanks. 
For MapR they have command which dumps the configuration
# hadoop conf -dump 
But I really wanted to know if there something like this for Apache hadoop.